# Raspberry PI and UBLOX Neo-7N / I2C Connection

Tags: i2c, gps

I am trying to read positioning data from a UBLOX Neo-7N Module via I2C serial connection.

I am using the Adafruit_I2C Python library to acomplish that.

The i2cdevice is connected correctly and I can establish a connection. I wrote a script to read the bit stream and display the NMEA data.

Now I have the following problem:

Immediately after startup the script works without problems for a short time. As at this point no I have no satellite fixes no proper data is displayed.

As soon as I get fixes and I would be able to receive position data, I get the error:

> Error accessing 0x42: Check your I2C address

As I am able to receive data at the beginning I am a bit confused why I get continues reading errors as soon as information would be available.

I was checking the web of course and only assumption I can make at the moment is that it could have to do something with the clock- baudrate of the I2C port?

Comment: I'd say poor or incorrect connections are the most likely error.  Download i2c-tools (sudo apt-get install i2c-tools) and see what i2cdetect -y 1 has to say.

Comment: already working with i2c-tools. i2cdetect detects the device without any problems. also measured the connection. Nothing wrong there. As i said, it works well as long as I don't have a fix on satellites that means no data. As soon as a get complete NMEA data the reading errors start...

Comment: Surely that points to an error in your code?

Comment: Nope, don't think the code is wrong. I was guessing that this problem is caused by some wrong hardware/firmware settings. Baudrate could be... but it is set for 100kbit on the pie and the gps module is able to handle 400kb so I dont know if that is the problem. And I dont know how to change the baudrate on the pi. Would really appreciante your help.

Comment: To set the baud rate see /boot/overlays/README.

Comment: After further research I guess I have found the problem. The GPS receriver applies abitrary clock stretching which the PIs i2c driver can not handle. Anbody has an idea or good tutorial how I can work around with bit banging? Thank you so much1

Comment: My [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library supports bit banging (with clock stretching). C http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#bbI2COpen, Python http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bb_i2c_open.

Comment: Ah, thats you. Thank you for that great library at that point. Though I am too unexperienced to get it working it seems.Could I ask you for one more favor. Could you have a look at https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/u-blox7-V14_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_%28GPS.G7-SW-12001%29_Public.pdf Page 15. There is the sequence to read a specific register from the ublox. How would I realize that request with your library? Thank you so much already :)

Comment: That's just a standard I2C read.  You specify the register to read and the number of bytes.  So in my bit bang terms you need 4 0x42 (set address) 2 (start) 7 1 REG (select register REG) 2 (start) 6 N (read N bytes from REG) 3 (STOP) 0 (End), i.e. 4 0x42 2 7 1 REG 2 6 N 3 0.  You need to choose REG and N.  It's probably quickest to experiment using pigs.  E.g. pigs bi2co 2 3 50000, then pigs bi2cz 2 4 0x42 2 7 1 REG 2 6 N 3 0.  pigs bi2cc 2 when you are done.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts! Unfortunately it does not seem to work: pi.bb_i2c_zip(3,[2,4,0x42,2,7,1,0xfd,2,6,1,3,0]) returns (-82L, ''). It is correct that when I defined the pins over your library that the i2cdetect can not detect the device anymore as the pins are switched to general gpio mode? ... Damn it ... i have that feeling that I am almost over the finishing line :)

Comment: You don't need the initial 2 with Python.  The 2 is used to identify the SDA GPIO from pigs.  In Python the SDA GPIO is specified as the first parameter of the call, i.e. pi.bb_i2c_zip(2,[4,0x42,2,7,1,0xfd,2,6,1,3,0]).  Note,SDA is 2 not 3 although you can swap them if you must as long as you are consistent with the open/close/zip calls.

Comment: I defined the pins as bb_i2c_open(3,5,50000) as the 3 and 5 pin are the ones with the build in pull-up resistors. isnt that right?

Comment: pigpio only uses Broadcom GPIO numbers.  SDA is GPIO 2, SCL is GPIO 3.  Yes they are on pins 3 and 5 but you have to use the GPIO number, not the pin number.

Comment: Its working! Thank you so much. I now hope I am able to retrieve the uncorrupted data. ill let you know if I was successfull.

Comment: Everything is working now! saved my day. thank you so much1

Comment: That is good to know.  I do not have any I2C devices which do clock stretching so I I have to hope I have not made too many mistakes.